# Checking if user came from intent

Tags: java, android

I am wondering how I can accomplish checking if an activity was started with an intent.

**What I have tried:**

I have tried checking if the object was null, but due to my setup, I cannot check that.  I have also tried executing with a code, but that failed too.

**My code:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("Title", one);
intent.putExtra("Description", two);

/////////////////////////

Intent intent = getIntent();

String title = intent.getStringExtra("Title");
String description = intent.getStringExtra("Description");
```

Many thanks!

Comment: All activities are started with an Intent - it's up to you to include relevant extras, or check if they are absent.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I wasn't aware of this, thank you for telling me.  What is the way of telling if it was launched by the default intent instead of a custom one?  Many thanks, Pawel!

Comment: You have to check if extras You provide to Intent that launches the activity are set. Other applications should not provide any extras, which will be an indicator it was not started by You.

Comment: If you want to know if your `Activity` is launched from the launcher, check this `getIntent().getAction() == Intent.ACTION_MAIN`. I believe you have set your main Activity's IntentFilter to include `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />` in the `AndroidManifest`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**All activities are started with an Intent**,

But we can check is Intent has detail in bundle or not?
        like in your case -

```
            Intent intent = getIntent();

            if( intent!= null && intent.getExtras() != null
                    && !intent.getExtras().getString("Title").equals("")
                    && !intent.getExtras().getString("Description").equals("") ) {

                // Activity started with sending title & description

            }
            else {
                // Activity started without sending title & description
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

just replace this line.

**Intent intent = getIntent();**

To

**Intent intent = getIntent().getExtra();**

you forgot to add .getExtra().